# Verb for 'try to find something you have in common with somebody'

Tags: vocabulary

Is there a verb which means 'try to find something in common with someone'? In this context for example:

- Everyone has the urge to commit a murder sometimes, we both do too.
- Don't you try to ... (with me), you criminal!

Keep in mind that this probably isn't  a perfect example, but I hope you understand what I mean. I thought of 'sympathize' for a while, but it is not quite what I'm looking for..

Comment: You might try [_empathize_](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/empathy?show=0&t=1356604120).

Comment: **agree**, **concur**. *"We concur fully," reply others, "in the objection to this part of the plan, but we can never agree that a reference of impeachments to the judiciary authority would be an amendment of the error.*
Federalist Papers -James Madison

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A fairly standard way to say this is ***to find [common ground](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_ground_%28communication_technique%29)*** with someone else. It is used as a communication technique.

The term itself derives from the old practice of a town having a *commons*, a parcel of land shared or held in common by all residents.

Comment: This is very close to what I meant!

Answer (score 1):

In a psychological context, finding common ground would be called **establishing a rapport**.

This technique is used to build trust and help people feel more comfortable communicating with a psychologist or doctor, but can also used in business and social contexts.

Answer (score -1):

*Relate* is the best single-word I can think of.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/relate

```
5. to establish a social or sympathetic relationship with a person or thing
```